# Finding stationary point of $y=\frac{\ln(x)}{x + 1}$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, stationary-point

I’ve been attempting to sketch the function

$y=\frac{\ln(x)}{x + 1}$

However, I’ve been having some trouble calculating the position of the stationary point.

I assume the correct way to calculate this is to differentiate the function and set the result to 0. I have

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+1+x \ln(x)}{x(x+1)^2}=0$

This yields

$x+1-x\ln(x) = 0$

Which can also be written as

$x = e^{1+\frac{1}{x}}$

I’m unsure of how to proceed from here though. So what steps do I need to take now in order to find the x-coordinate of the stationary point of the function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lambert W function? Because that's how the solution to $x+1-x\cdot\log x=0$ is expressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$y= \dfrac{\ln x}{x+1}$$

we have $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1/x\cdot(x+1)-\ln x}{(x+1)^2}$$

If $dy/dx =0$, then

\begin{align}
\dfrac{x+1}{x} &= \ln x \\
\iff x &= \exp\bigg(\dfrac{x+1}{x}\bigg) \\
&= \exp(1)\exp(1/x) \\
&= e\exp(1/x) \\
\iff x &= \dfrac{1}{W(1/e)}
\end{align}

where $W$ is a Lambert $W$ function. You can find more details about this function [here](https://m.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.html).